Restrict Electron webContents.findInPage() search to specific page element(s)
Using Electron's webContents module and its findInPage() method, one can search the entire page for a text pattern. However, when implementing this with a modal Find window, the search pattern entered in its text input field also gets highlighted (see image), which feels kind of stupid. I would like to restrict the search to specific elements in the page, such that only matches found inside those elements are highlighted. Is there any way that can be achieved?


I am having the same question. Did you found a solution yet?

@cpc: No. I guess Electron simply piggybacks on Chromium here, and that there is no capability built into the feature to direct the search to specific page elements. You might have noticed that the Search feature in Chrome sometimes points to text in invisible elements, for example.
